# Как восстановить JPEG файл?

Tags: обработка-изображений, jpeg, восстановление, recovery

Не могу открыть JPEG-файлы.

Проблема конкретно заключается в том, что разрешение у снимков почему-то стало 1х1 пиксель то есть 0 Мегапикселей, в то время как размер файлов варьируется от 850 кБ до 2.5 МБ, то есть информация об изображениях все еще как-то хранится.

Пробовал изменить размер изображения вручную, через фотошоп, но он не открывает картинки размером 1х1 пиксель. Также пробовал восстановить файлы программами Hetman Partition Recovery, JPEG Recovery Pro 6, Stellar Phoenix JPEG Repair, но эти программы будто не видят проблем с фотографиями, и после обработки в них ничего не меняется.

Если вы знаете сервисы или программы, которые могут восстановить файлы, прикреплённые ниже, поделитесь.

Ссылки на файлы:

- [Картинка 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1etf_y0LjlCZkpDNUZqcUxQZGs)
- [Картинка 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1etf_y0LjlCNjE0V0w5a2tjZHc)

Comment: Без файлов - гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов извиняюсь, не углядел, добавил ссылки на изображения

Comment: @tupolobik Вы не дали доступа на чтение ссылок на рисунки с Google Drive, нужно выставить разрешение на чтение этих ссылок всем кто владеет ссылкой.

Comment: Блин, думал что открыто по умолчанию, поменял настройки и сделал доступным для всех.

Comment: просьба повторно открыть вопрос, так как были загружены файлы-образцы, и вопрос не содержит лишней информации, а создавать дупликат не хотелось бы